Error with lim math mode

please help me type this. I tried many times but it's still wrong.

Hi and welcome. Please show us your attempt.

Show us what you wrote, note that the image is wrong, and that \lim should not have limits under it in text mode. And the text "lim" should be upright not italic like in the image.

This is what I wrote before: $\lim_{t\to\t_0}|\vec{r}(t)- \overline{a}|= \vec{0}$ as $\lim_{t\to\t_0}\overrightarrow{r(t)} =\vec{a}$, khi đó: $$|r(t) - a|=\sqrt{[f(t)-a_1]^2+[g(t)-a_2]^2 + [h(t)-a_n]^2 + ...}$$ understood as r(t) - a.

Please [edit] your code into your question, and make sure it's formatted the way you want it to be.

This is the correct way to write the contents of the image. As mention in my comment, limits on lim does not go under when written in text mode math, it disturbs the line spacing.
Additionally I create a \abs macro because |r(t)-a| is wrong, it should be \lvert r(t)-a \rvert and then it is just easier to use \abs{...}. See the mathtools manual for what \abs can also do.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}

$\lim_{t\to t_0} \abs{\vec{r}(t)-\bar{x}}$ as
$\lim_{t\to t_0} \vec{r}(t) = \vec{a}$, then
$\abs{r(t)-a}=\sqrt{[f(t)-a_1]^2 + \dots}$ understood as vector
$r(t)-a$.


\end{document}


Thank you so much! I tried your way and it worked!

A serious problem with the screenshot you're supposed to recreate is that the math typesetting it contains is wrong in several ways. Chief among them are (a) "lim" should be typeset using upright (aka "roman") lettering instead of slanted (aka "italic") lettering; (b) in running text, the argument of \lim should not be placed immediately below it; and (c) the long expression involving a square root term should be typeset in display mode on a centered line all by itself. The back-and-forth between short and long arrows, as well as the notational confusion between vec{r} and \mathrm{r} and between \vec{a} and \mathrm{a}, also seem like poor design choices.
Taking these concerns into account, I've come up with the following.

\documentclass{article} % or some other appropriate document class
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' and '\mathclap' macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}

$\lim_{t\to t_0} \abs{\vec{r}(t)-\vec{a}}=\vec{0}$ as
$\lim_{t\to t_0} \vec{r}(t)=\vec{a}$, then:
\[
\abs{\mathrm{r}(t)-\mathrm{a}}=
\sqrt{[f(t)-a_1]^2+[g(t)-a_2]^2+[h(t)-a_3]^2+\dots}
\]
understood as vector $\mathrm{r}(t)-\mathrm{a}$.

\bigskip
wrong:

\smallskip
$\lim\limits_{\mathclap{t\to t_0}} \abs{\vec{r}(t)-\vec{a}}=\vec{0}$ as
$\lim\limits_{\mathclap{t\to t_0}} \vec{r}(t)=\vec{a}$, then: \dots
\end{document}


The image is what I needed to write by Latex, which was took from Microsoft Word. I have a homework asked to write by Latex. I just 'new" to Latex so, I don't really understand the complete meaning of the commands. Thank you so much for your explaination about the meaning of commands. This is what I wrote before $\lim_{t\to\t_0}|\vec{r}(t)- \overline{a}|= \vec{0}$ as $\lim_{t\to\t_0}\overrightarrow{r(t)} =\vec{a}$, khi đó: $$|r(t) - a|=\sqrt{[f(t)-a_1]^2+[g(t)-a_2]^2 + [h(t)-a_n]^2 + ...}$$ understood as r(t) - a.
